# How to create an interface which implements setSingleChoiceItems and setMultipleChoiceItems in Android

Tags: android, material-design

I wanted to create an interface which implements `setSingleChoiceItems` and `setMultipleChoiceItems`. So that when I call this interface/API, it will do the same as the android `setSingleChoiceItems` and `setMultipleChoiceItems` API does.

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to do have the same functionality, why don't you use the provided API?

The original API is not an interface, it's a class which you can extend and add to it's functionality. You can read more in the official docs 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: I am writing an inerface AlertDialog which does the same as Android Alert Dialog. Wanted to to setSingleChoiceItems and SetMultipleChoiceItems functionality to it

Comment: @SharunVargheseSamuel look into the source code and try doing something similar.